# BasicHttpBinding to Project Server (SharePoint Server) causes a 401 error

Tags: c#, basichttpbinding

I am trying to create a BasicHttpBinding to a Project Server. But I keep getting a 401 error.

Infrastructure:

Server A (IP: 192.168.123.10) is IIS 7.5 and Server B (IP: 192.168.123.20) is SharePoint (Project Server 2010). Both are found in a Domain. 
The following test Web application (MVC) has been published on Server A.

```
HomeController.cs:

using System;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

            const int MAXSIZE = 500000000;
            BasicHttpBinding binding = null;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
            String pwaUrl = "http://192.168.123.20:24010";
            const string svcRouter = "/_vti_bin/PSI/ProjectServer.svc";

           // Create a binding for HTTP.
           binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);


            binding.Name = "basicHttpConf";
            binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = MAXSIZE;
            binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = MAXSIZE;
            binding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text;
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;
            binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None;


            // The endpoint address is the ProjectServer.svc router for all public PSI calls.
            EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(pwaUrl + svcRouter);

             SvcResource.ResourceClient _resourceClient;


             NetworkCredential credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;


            _resourceClient = new SvcResource.ResourceClient(binding, address);

            _resourceClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = credentials;
            _resourceClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;



           ViewBag.ThreadUser = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;


            ViewBag.TESTUSER = _resourceClient.GetCurrentUserUid();


            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Web.config

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="true"/>

<authorization>
<deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Now in the function `ViewBag.TESTUSER = _resourceClient.GetCurrentUserUid();` I get a 401 error that I can't explain.

Error message:

```
[WebException: Der Remoteserver hat einen Fehler zurückgegeben: (401) Nicht autorisiert.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +7866004
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout) +99

[MessageSecurityException: Die HTTP-Anforderung ist beim Clientauthentifizierungsschema "Ntlm" nicht autorisiert. Vom Server wurde der Authentifizierungsheader "NTLM" empfangen.]
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +4729427
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +1725
   SvcResource.Resource.GetCurrentUserUid() +0
   SvcResource.ResourceClient.GetCurrentUserUid() +52
```

Do you know why this is happening? Do I have to change settings on the Project Server 2010, or maybe change the Active Directory settings?